# How to press a key to play a sound on React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, playback

**My work frame:** Next.JS v13.4.19

**What I am doing:**  Trying to play soundbites when I press a certain key.

**How I am doing it:** The function handlePlay() look for certain key press and triggers the play() function for a specific soundbite when it matches.

So far my function works just fine. If I press Q, S or D, it will play the file I want.

**My problem:** it works *only* if I click one of the buttons first.

**My goal**: to play these soundbites from the keyboard *as soon as the page has loaded*.

**My code**

```
"use client"

export default function Home() {
  
  function handlePlay(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 81) {
      kick.play()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 83) {
      hat.play()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 68) {
      snare.play()
    }
  };


  return (
    <div onKeyDown={(e) => handlePlay(e)}>
      <audio id="kick" src="kick.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="hat" src="hat.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="snare" src="snare.wav"></audio>

      <button onClick={() => kick.play()}>
        Kick
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => hat.play()}>
        Hat
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => snare.play()}>
        Snare
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your div wont capture keyup events unless you're actively pressing keys while the element (Or a child of the element) is focused. Try a `useEffect` hook that attaches the listener to the document instead of a specific div:

```
"use client"

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handlePlay)

    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handlePlay)
  }, [])
  
  function handlePlay(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 81) {
      kick.play()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 83) {
      hat.play()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 68) {
      snare.play()
    }
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <audio id="kick" src="kick.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="hat" src="hat.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="snare" src="snare.wav"></audio>

      <button onClick={() => kick.play()}>
        Kick
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => hat.play()}>
        Hat
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => snare.play()}>
        Snare
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```